# Как проверить наличие элемента в массиве Java

Tags: java

У меня есть два массива:

```java
int numberOf;

String arrayParX[] = new String[numberOfPar]; //Содержание массива:{"Картинки";"Видео";"Null";"Null";"Null";"Размер";"Объем"}

String arrayTableList = new String[numberOfTable]; //Содержание массива:{"Картинки","Размер"}
```

Как проверить наличие элементов arrayTableList в массиве arrayParX, массив может быть и 100+

Comment: какой должен быть результат на примере этих двух массивов?

Answer (score 0):

Используем перебор, берем первый элемент из одного массива и сверяем его с элементами из другого массива и так далее

```
int numberOf;

String arrayParX[] = new String[numberOfPar]; //Содержание массива:{"Картинки";"Видео";"Null";"Null";"Null";"Размер";"Объем"}

String arrayTableList = new String[numberOfTable]; //Содержание массива:{"Картинки","Размер"}

for(int i=0;i<=arrayTableList.length-1;i++)
{
   for(int j=0;j<=arrayParX.length-1;j++)
   {
      if(arrayTableList[i].equals(arrayParX[j]))
        {
           System.out.println("Совпадение");
        }
   }
}
```

возможно допустил синтаксическую ошибку, но надеюсь ход мысли понятен

Comment: 1. Не по теме, просто чтбы не было путаницы - строки сравнивают через equals

Comment: 2. Тоже коммент просто для информации. Если элементов сотни, то перебор вполне подходит. Если количество элементов растет, тысячи и десятки тысяч, то эффективнее будет использовать хешсет для поиска.

Comment: @tym32167 насчет equals согласен, уже исправил. по привычке поставил ==.

Comment: Почему не stream api, выглядит убого, да и если большие массивы   то пригодится параллельное выполнение,так что задачаэу надо со стримом делать